# Add sequential IDs to divs within a parent container with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add sequential IDs to all divs within a parent container so it looks like this.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="id1">content</div>
  <div id="id2">content</div>
  <div id="id3">content</div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$('#parent').children().each(function() {
  var count = 1;
  $(this).attr('id', 'id'+count);
  count++;
});
```

…and it just adds the ID of id1 to all divs.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Any time you find yourself generating this pattern, you are creating an anti-pattern where a class should be used instead.

Comment: Swap line 1 and 2.  Or change the first two lines to: `$('#parent').children().each(function(i) {
  var count = i+1;`

Comment: Yes because your count variable is always reset to 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var count = 1; 
 $('#parent').children().each(function() {
   $(this).attr('id', 'id'+count);
   count++;
});
```

Place your variable outside of the callback function and it will work.

Comment: Ah such a basic mistake. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `count` variable before the loop not in the loop.

Or

You can use index parameter of `each`

```
$('#parent').children().each(function(index) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'id' + index);
});
```

Comment: i guess should be: `$(this).attr('id', 'id' + (index + 1))`